# When sending emails through smtp do I need to setup DomainKeys and any kind of other email config?

Tags: smtp, gmail, email-bounces, domainkeys, email-server

When sending emails through gmails smtp (smtp.gmail.com) do I need to setup DomainKeys and any other kind of email config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How/what are you trying to send through gmail?  Are you configuring a standard email client to work with a gmail address?  If so, you're correct -- you don't need any special configuration.

Basic instructions on client setup is available here: http://mail.google.com/support/bin/topic.py?topic=12769

AFAIK, DKIM isn't supported yet on google app domains either.

Cheers,

M

Comment: Though SugarCRM